# Google oauth not closing login page in mobile devices

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I developed an application that uses the Google + API to authenticate the user using the following code snippet:

```
<div class="g-signin"
     data-callback="loginFinishedCallback"
     data-clientid="{My Client ID}"
     data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
     data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
 >
 </div>
```

This basically displays a Google Sign in button and when the user clicks on it, another window opens and they sign in. In desktop browsers everything works great but in mobile devices the second window opens and after the user logs in, Google doesn't close the login window so the user ends up staring at an empty page. In other words the callback function never gets called because the mobile browser doesn't close the new (login) window. Is there a way to work around this issue?

This is the javascript file Google provides:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Any luck finding an answer to this?

Comment: Which technology are you using for OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment--however I would like to see an answer for this question.  I am having the same problem with Google login redirecting mobile devices to blank page. Desktop Google login works perfectly fine. I am using OAuth2.0.

EDIT:

I solved this problem for my own framework. After tracing through and using a ton of var dumps I realized where google's redirect was dying out. The problem was that when the page redirected from my site's control to Google's authentication control, my $_SESSION redirect was lost. My other social logins (FB and LinkedIn) work with this method, however I had to add a catch for google specific redirect. I checked if the redirect was set and if not, made sure to set it there.

I hope this helps with your problem.